# finding a matching value in column and updating by vlookup or adress match

Tags: excel, match, vlookup, matching

I have a simple explanation of what I'm having trouble with.

Column A: List of 100 names (each Name exists 2 times)
Column B: Email Address associated with the names(each Name has emailadress)

Example:

```
      A1: James B1:oldmail@hotmail.com

      A10: James B10:newmail@hotmail.com
```

So I want to get this===>>

```
      A1:James B1:newmail@hotmail.com
```

Basically i want to use vlookup or adressmatch to update the email adress, when two values in Column A match.

How can i do this?

Comment: Are the corresponding entries in the same row?

Comment: you mean the matching Name values? they should be both in Column A

Comment: I should search for second value which is same in Column A which matches and then get ist Column B value and write it in to Column B of Column A s first matching value

Comment: Ah okay, now I got it. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: i am googling everything i can for vlookup and adressmatch, indexmatch but can not find it. I Need to be done with this before my presentation and i dont see myself finding it

Comment: Okay, some more questions. Do you need a dynamic solution to this? Are there any other distinct features between the corresponding pairs? How can I be sure that the mail adress I found is the new one and not the old one? Or is column B all old mail adresses from Row 1 to X and then all new mail adresses from Row X to the lastrow?

Comment: There are max 2 same values in my COlumn A. So there are only 2 JAMES, 2 Richards, 2 Michaels and so on. I want it to be dynamic, if thats possible. its not important which mail adress is new. Only Thing that matters is once i have second James, Richard, Michael and so on, i just want to take his email adress and overwrite it to the previous James, Richard, Michael's email adress area

Comment: Basically, i have one Name with old email and same Name with new email. By doing what i desired to do, i will update email adress of the old one, because the second name value has the new email adress

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115931/discussion-between-yigit-tanverdi-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

**Note: it will work if the column A each name have two times only**

If the Column A names appear one time it will considered as the new one in B column.

```
Sub test()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim incre As Long
    Dim flag As String
    flag = "no"
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    incre = 1
    ReDim names(lastrow, 2) As String
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        names(i, 1) = Range("A" & i).Value
        names(i, 2) = Range("B" & i).Value
    Next i
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        For j = i + 1 To lastrow
            If names(i, 1) = names(j, 1) Then
                flag = "yes"
                Range("C" & incre) = names(j, 1) & " Value: " & names(j, 2)
                incre = incre + 1
            End If
        Next j
        If flag = "no" Then
            Range("C" & incre) = names(i, 1) & " Value: " & names(i, 2)
        Else
            flag = "no"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

---

[image]

[image]